# Laravel whereHas children in Blade template

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I currently have the concept of Products and Slots as Models; A Slot is a time slot, and a product can have 1 or many time slots.

That is to say that One Product can have many Slots. lay example being as below:

Product - "Cookery Class"
Slots - ['2023-12-12 11:00:00', '2023-12-12 13:00:00']

I currently query this like below:

```
Product::whereHas('slots' ,function ($query) {
        $query->whereDate('start_time', '=', $this->booking_date);
    })->get();
```

This works as expected, however inside my Blade template when I want to list the slots available calling

```
{{$product->slots()}}
```

Get's all slots as per the relationship defined in the Model and takes no notice of the WhereDate clause - how can I within my Blade template iterate through the slots for a given Product with the WhereDate clause of Slots. Ideally I don't want to write another query for this.

Comment: Basic Laravel, `->slots()` returns a relationship, so you are getting everything... `->slots` returns the (loaded) relationship, but you missed the eager load, so you would still get everything, just you got back the products that matched the relationship condition. @TimLewis correctly explained the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `->whereHas()` to `->withWhereHas()`:

```php
$products = Product::withWhereHas('slots' ,function ($query) {
  $query->whereDate('start_time', '=', $this->booking_date);
})->get();
```

This will "Eager Load" the `slots` Models, as well as filter your `Product` records to only those that satisfy the nested `->whereDate()` clause.

Next, in your `.blade.php` file, don't do `->slots()`. There's 2 issues with that:

1. `->slots()` with `()` is always a new query, and completely ignores the eager loading done via `->withWhereHas()`
2. The query from `->slots()` isn't actually executed, so doing `{{ $product->slots() }}` will likely output nothing, or, as you stated, all `slot` records, even those that do not satisfy the `->whereDate` clause you specified.

It would need to be:

```php
@foreach($product->slots()->get() as $slot)
  {{ $slot }}
@endforeach
```

But again, you wouldn't want to do this, as it's now an N+1 query issue, where each iteration of `$products` executes a new query, along with the other issues mentioned above.

Your final `.blade.php` code should be:

```php
@foreach($products as $product)
  @foreach($product->slots as $slot)
    {{ $slot }}
  @endforeach
@endforeach
```

---

https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads-with-relationship-existence